# C++ "system()" in C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, system

I am currently developing an application in C# which needs to work sort of like a "Command Prompt", therefore I was wondering whether the C++ function

```
int system ( const char * command );
```

in `cstdlib`exists in C#?

A reference to an dynamic-link library containing this function would be accepted aswell.

Comment: @dotTutorials By CMD You mean "Command Prompt" ?

Comment: `system()` isn't needed for a program that needs to operate like a command prompt. Only use it if you actually need to send commands to the _system's_ command prompt. For writing your own command prompt-like program you can write your own command line parser, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look into `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx

Comment: Also note that you may want to call Process.Start("cmd.exe") and then pass text to the standard input of that, or you may want to execute some directly.  It's hard to tell which you want based on the OP.

Comment: Thanks, got it Servy 'n qehgt. The help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute program from an application then you can use 'Process' class,it's insanely easy,

```
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
 static void Main()
 {
Process.Start("MyApp.exe");
 }
}
```

You might use a Console Application project template in Visual Studio,
[image]

Comment: You may want to run a command shell command from a winform or WPF app; it doesn't need to *be* a console app to *execute* code to a console shell.

Comment: @Servy you are right ,but the questioner asks for "work sort of like a "Command Prompt"

Comment: Have you ever written, or seen, a winform/WPF application that was just a prettier shell?  You can make a winform app that acts like a command prompt.