# Invoking Powershell command directly from C#

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, dll

Let's say there is a powershell command `Do-Something`, from the library `C:\dosth.dll`, which is based on .NET Framework 4.5.

How do I directly perform the action (just as I use `Do-Something` in Powershell) through this library dll?
Something like

```cs
Assembly dosth = new Assembly("C:\dosth.dll");
...
```

The problem is, the command is actually a class in .NET, how do I construct an instance correctly with right properties, and which method should I call to perform the command?

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68352130/10024425

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806427/c-system-in-c-sharp

Comment: The following may also be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67409580/10024425

Comment: @McFlurry Is there anything same?

Comment: Sorry, I believe I copied the wrong source. This thread may have the answer you’re looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands

Comment: @McFlurry Not at all. I specifically said "directly" and gave a code snippet as beginning